# How to add spinner while loading data in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, spinner

I want to add spinner while loading data from database. For fetching data I am using react-hook. Here is my code ,how can I add spinner here?

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useInventories from "../../../hooks/useInventories";
import Inventory from "../Inventory/Inventory";

const Inventories = () => {
const [inventories] = useInventories();

return (
    <>
      <div id="inventory" className="container mt-5 ">
        <h2 className="text-center my-5 text-primary ">Inventory</h2>
        <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 border-1 ">
          {inventories.slice(0, 6).map((inventory) => (
            <Inventory key={inventory._id} inventory={inventory}></Inventory>
          ))}
          
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </>
  );
};

export default Inventories;
```

It take a little bit time to load data from mongodb. So I want to add spinner loading before that.

Comment: return the loading state from the react hook, set loading to initially true in the react hook and then false when the data is fetched or there is an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do solution with useEffect. Basically initial loading is true and it becomes false when you have inventories data. I also see that you are using tailwind so you can set spinner icon animation directly with `animate-spin`

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useInventories from "../../../hooks/useInventories";
import Inventory from "../Inventory/Inventory";

const Inventories = () => {
const [inventories] = useInventories();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
    if(inventories?.length > 0) {
       setLoading(false)
  }

}, [inventories])

return (
    <>
      {loading <SpinnerComponent/> }
      {!loading
      <div id="inventory" className="container mt-5 ">
        <h2 className="text-center my-5 text-primary ">Inventory</h2>
        <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 border-1 ">
          {inventories.slice(0, 6).map((inventory) => (
            <Inventory key={inventory._id} inventory={inventory}></Inventory>
          ))}
          
        </div>
        
      </div>}
      
    </>
  );
};

export default Inventories;
```

Comment: ` if (loading) {
    return <Loading></Loading>;
  }` after useEffect i have write this.It worked. Thanks

Comment: And I am actually using bootstrap. But thanks for letting me know about  **animate-spin** since I am practicing tailwind at this moment